# How to back up android note 4 that won't boot up?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have a note 4 official firmware, that won't boot up anymore. It goes into `mmc_read failed`. On the center it says `Downloading... do not turn off target!!` but nothing happens.

I tried booting into safe mode, and this happens. If I don't boot on safe mode, it get stuck on the main screen with the logo.

Is there a way I can still back up some of my data from the phone. Because I want to probably get it replaced.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

take the battery out, hold the power button on for 1 min to drain all residual power. Replace battery and power up normally. This has worked with mine but am not game to power it off anymore.